# finding the maximum sum in Matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, sum, max, dynamic-programming

**Input**: A 2-dimensional `NxN` -symmetric Matrix - with `NxN` positive elements.

**Output**: A 2-dimensional matrix of `NxN` size with `N` selected elements such that its summation is the maximum among all possible selection. Other elements that are not selected are zero. In other words, we should select `N` elements from matrix to return **maximum** sum.

**Requirement**:  If the dimension of matrix is `4*4`, we should select **4** integer. Every row and column in matrix should not be used more than **2** times.
For example if we have `4*4` matrix, the following element could be selected:

```
(1,2)
(2,3)
(3,4)
(4,1)
```

but if we select `(1,2)`and `(4,1)`, we cannot select `(1,3)`, because we used `1` two times.

IS there an efficient algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Is there an efficient algorithm to get someone else to do my homework?

Comment: It is not homework, it is just part of my project. I just need the name of algorithm.

Comment: Can we select 12, 23, 34, 14?

Comment: yes we can select them.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is in that weird place where it's not obvious that there's a solution polytope with integral vertices and yet its similarity to general matching discourages me from looking for an NP-hardness reduction. Algorithms for general matching are complicated enough that modifying one would be a daunting prospect even if there were a way to do it, so my advice would be to use an integer program solver. There's a formulation like

```
maximize sum_{ij} w_{ij} x_{ij}
subject to
sum_{ij} x_{ij} = n
forall k, sum_i x_{ik} + sum_j x_{kj} ≤ 2
forall ij, x_{ij} in {0, 1},
```

where `w_{ij}` is the `ij`th element of the weight matrix.